# Problem with TLS identity not verified

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, ocsp

I run a CA server "Microsoft CA Server Enterprise" and I generate certificates then bind the cert to my site. In all clients in my network, I add the cert with

```
certutil -addstore ca org.cer
```

When my clients browse the org site, Google Chrome shows error with https and says that "identity not verified"

First I thought the problem was with the online responder, so I ran OCSP and add AIA and CRL, but does not work. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: I'm guessing SHA1 signatures. Can you please check? (Details here: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/identity-not-verified-in-chrome) (Archived here: https://archive.today/OFjCb)

Comment: hello, i  read links before but i do not understand that means sha1 is vulnerable ! or something like that , and if i change encryption be correct ? tnx for your advise

Comment: It looks like you are using a self-signed certificate for your website and expect that all browsers fully trust your self-signed cert. If this is the case, please read up, how TLS, X.509 and PKI works.

Comment: @sebix dear friend i run ca server this is not self sign i run pki server and do not use iis self sign certificate very difrence between cert of ca server and generate cert self sign via iis !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

1) Does it work in Internet Explorer? (If not, then check if you're having a chain-of-trust issue.)
2) Is the certificate using SHA1? If yes, then change to SHA-256 or SHA-512. (Chrome doesn't like SHA1 anymore.)
3) Is the RSA key size >= 2048? -> If yes, then you're fine. If no, then increase RSA key size.
4) Is your certificate to an FQDN or a simple one word name? If simple one word name, then change to resolvable FQDN.

Comment: 1.work,2.yes,3.yes,4.your means ca server name? Ca server in domain